# Magento 2 Export Single Entry in CSV

Tags: magento2, backend, export

While exporting (CSV) data from admin grid, if I select single entry, even though it is exporting entire sheet. I am not able to export single entry.using below code. Please suggest something.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sm\Sample\Controller\Adminhtml\Sample;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ExportInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class ExportCsv extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $_fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Export subscribers grid to CSV format
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
       $fileName = 'exportCsv.csv';
        $content = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Sm\Sample\Block\Adminhtml\Sample\Grid'
        )->setSaveParametersInSession(
            true
        )->getCsv();

        return $this->_fileFactory->create($fileName, $content);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Sm_Sample::sample');
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot export a single record by check the massaction checkbox.
You need to shorten your list by using **Filter fields** and click **Export** button.

[image]

Comment: But in all customers we can export single entry also .

Comment: I bet your class is extended from `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid`,  so you cannot export single entry like Customers Listing page do, what is made by using M2 UiComponent.